# pointer to char vs char pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    c='z';
// Pointer to char
   char *d;
    d=&c;
    printf("%c",*d);

// char pointer
    char *d1="karthick";
    printf("%s",d1);
    return 0;
}
```

I have declared pointer to a char and char pointer (string) . I could see that their way of declaration are same then how they varies in function?

Comment: A pointer can point to either a single value or an array of values. A string is just an array of `char`, ending with a null character.

Comment: `pointer to char` and `char pointer` are the same thing. After the comment `// char pointer`, you could write `d="karthick"; printf("%s",d);` and the code would generate the same output. The difference is the `printf` format string: `"%c"` versus `"%s"`.  `%c` says you only want to see one character that the pointer points to. That works for both `d` and `d1`. `%s` says you want to see the string of characters that the pointer points to. That won't work with `d` because `d` doesn't point to a string. In summary, both `d` and `d1` are char pointers, but `d1` points to a string, and `d` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`d` and `d1` are exactly the same thing.  Both point to a *single* `char` object; it's just that in `d1`'s case, that single `char` object is the first character in a *string*, whereas `d` points to a single character that isn't part of a larger string:

```
    char        char *
    +---+       
 c: |'z'| <---  d
    +---+
     ...
    +---+
    |'k'| <---- d1
    +---+
    |'a'|
    +---+
    |'r'|
    +---+
    |'t'|
    +---+
    |'h'|
    +---+
    |'i'|
    +---+
    |'c'|
    +---+
    |'k'|
    +---+
    | 0 |
    +---+
```